# format of double quotation marks in biblatex with cleanthesis

Tags: biblatex, templates, cleanthesis

I am writing thesis with a downloaded template of `scrreprt`. I find a problem with the reference format. The following picture is as my reference shows now

[image]

The problem is that the double quotation mark is weird as one side of it is below. The expected one should be like this:

[image]

I looked inside the setting file and I found some settings about `biblatex`

```
\RequirePackage[                    % use biblatex for bibliography
    backend=\cthesis@bibsys,        %   - use biber backend (bibtex replacement) or bibtex
    bibencoding=utf8,               %   - use auto file encode
    style=ieee,             %   - use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    natbib=true,                    %   - allow natbib commands
    hyperref=true,                  %   - activate hyperref support
    backref=false,                  %   - activate backrefs
    isbn=false,                     %   - don't show isbn tags
    url=false,                      %   - don't show url tags
    doi=false,                      %   - don't show doi tags
    urldate=long,                   %   - display type for dates
    sorting=none,
%   maxnames=3,%
%   minnames=1,%
%   maxbibnames=5,%
%   minbibnames=3,%
%   maxcitenames=2,%
%   mincitenames=1%
]{biblatex}
```

But I don't know how to handle the double marks issue.

Comment: This is controlled by the `csquotes` package, which `biblatex` uses when loaded.  Is your whole document in german or just this one entry in the bibliography?

Comment: @AndrewSwann No. My document is in english and all entries have such problem when double mark is used.

Comment: What options are passed to `csquotes`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have fixed it by changing german to english. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewSwann Do you want to write up an answer? You won't be surprised to know that [`cleanthesis` indeed loads `csquotes` with the `style=german` option](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/master/cleanthesis.sty#L279).

Comment: @moewe Done - thanks for the pointer to the poster's class

Comment: Exactly facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes in `biblatex` use the styles set by `csquotes` if this package is loaded.

According to those with crystal balls you are using [`cleanthesis.sty`](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/master/cleanthesis.sty#L279).
One indication that you are indeed using this is the unusual `backend=\cthesis@bibsys` option passed to `biblatex`.
A more standard way to write such things would be to use a `\PassOptionstoClass` command in the style file.

Now `cleanthesis.sty` loads `csquotes` as follows:

```
\RequirePackage[                    % advanced quotes
    strict=true,                    %   - warning are errors now
    style=german                    %   - german quotes
]{csquotes}
```

It is the `german` style that is producing the types of quotes you see.   You can override this by putting

```
\setquotestyle{english}
```

in your document.  This will turn off the multilingual support of `csquotes` and make all quotes of the form you request.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[strict=true,style=german]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{A test quote}, in \verb+german+ style.

\setquotestyle{english}

\enquote{A test quote}, in \verb+english+ style.

\end{document}
```